# Swift 5.2 Xcode 11.4 Vapor 4.0.0 how should I code the PK in my model?

Tags: swift, xcode, postgresql, vapor

My `Package.swift` file looks like:

```
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/vapor.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent.git", from: "4.0.0-rc"),
.package(url: "https://github.com/vapor/fluent-postgres-driver.git", from: "2.0.0-rc")
```

My `config.swift` file looks like:

```
app.databases.use(.postgres(
    hostname: Environment.get("DATABASE_HOST") ?? "localhost",
    username: Environment.get("DATABASE_USERNAME") ?? "postgres",
    password: Environment.get("DATABASE_PASSWORD") ?? "secret",
    database: Environment.get("DATABASE_NAME") ?? "mydb2"
), as: .psql)
```

My model looks like:

```
import Fluent
import Vapor


final class Complaint: Model, Content {

    static let schema = "cw_complaint5"

    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

    @Field(key: "issue_description")
    var issue_description: String

    // etc.
    init() { }
}
```

In Xcode, the project builds OK, and this `GET` route runs OK:

```
http://localhost:8080/complaint
```

But when I run the `POST` route, I get an error in the response body:

```
{
    "error": true,
    "reason": "Value of type 'UUID' required for key 'id'."
}
```

In Vapor 3, the `POST` route worked fine for both inserting a new row (omit the ID in the JSON request body) and updating an existing row. The table description on PostgreSQL 11.3 looks like:

```
mydb2=# \d+ cw_complaint5
                                              Table "public.cw_complaint5"
        Column        |          Type           | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
----------------------+-------------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                   | integer                 |           | not null |         | plain    |              | 
 row                  | smallint                |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 document_number      | integer                 |           | not null |         | plain    |              |
...etc...
county_id            | integer                 |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 city_id              | integer                 |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
 operator_id          | integer                 |           |          |         | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "cw_complaint5_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
Check constraints:
    "cw_complaint5_row_check" CHECK ("row" >= 0)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "cw_complaint5_city_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (city_id) REFERENCES cw_city5(id)
    "cw_complaint5_county_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (county_id) REFERENCES cw_county5(id)
    "cw_complaint5_operator_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (operator_id) REFERENCES cw_operator5(id)

(END)
```

The request body of the failiing `POST` request (update existing row) looks like:

```
{"id":729,"issue_description":"test","document_number":99,"api_state_code":88,"api_county_code":11,"section":22,"city_id":51,"county_id":56,"operator_id":4415}
```

Comment: Could you show the code for your POST endpoint?

Comment: OK here are the (successful) GET and the (not successful) POST:     app.get("complaint") { req in
        Complaint.query(on: req.db).all()
    }

    app.post("complaint") { req -> EventLoopFuture<Complaint> in
        let complaint = try req.content.decode(Complaint.self)
        return complaint.create(on: req.db)
            .map { complaint }
    }

Comment: I see it does a create, so I wouldn't expect it to update an existing row. If I remove the id from the json request body and hope it will insert a row, I get: {
    "error": true,
    "reason": "server: column \"id\" is of type integer but expression is of type uuid (transformAssignedExpr)"
}

Comment: I tried various permutations of the id in the model. This is the only one the build accepted:
    @ID(key: .id)
    var id: UUID?

Comment: If `id` column in the database is already autoincrement integer then you shouldn't change your model's id to `UUID`. To make fluent work with autoincrement as far as I remember you should just mark your id as autogeneratable something like this `@ID(custom: "id", generatedBy: .database) var id: Int?`

Comment: Find me on Discord as `iMike#3049` and I will try to help you with any Vapor question

Comment: OK I set the id in the model as you suggested and did a POST to try to insert a row (omitting the id in the json request):   {
    "error": true,
    "reason": "server: null value in column \"id\" violates not-null constraint (ExecConstraints)"
}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215243/discussion-between-magula-and-imike).

Comment: Yes this works OK: @ID(custom: "id", generatedBy: .database) var id: Int? The trick was to alter table to serialize id:
mydb2=# ALTER TABLE cw_complaint5 DROP COLUMN id;
ALTER TABLE
mydb2=# ALTER TABLE cw_complaint5 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
ALTER TABLE

Answer (score 4):

Your issue here is that the `Complaint` model's ID type is `UUID`, but in your `POST` request body, you are passing in an `Int` value. Since you are migrating an existing project that already has a database defined with integer IDs, the best solution for this is to change your model's ID type.

Because Fluent 4 attempts to support all databases, by default it only supports UUID ID types. You can have a custom ID type, like this:

```swift
@ID(custom: "id", generatedBy: .database) var id: Int?
```

This will allow your model to work with your current database table structure and take in integer IDs in your `POST` request body.

Your model will look like this in the end:

```swift
final class Complaint: Model, Content {

    static let schema = "cw_complaint5"

    @ID(custom: "id", generatedBy: .database)
    var id: Int?

    @Field(key: "issue_description")
    var issue_description: String

    // etc.
    init() { }
}
```

Comment: Coding id as you suggested and attempting  POST to insert a row (with no id in the json request), I get "server: null value in column \"id\" violates not-null constraint (ExecConstraints)"

Answer (score 0):

Solution: serialize the table in PostgreSQL:

```
mydb2=# ALTER TABLE cw_complaint5 DROP COLUMN id;

mydb2=# ALTER TABLE cw_complaint5 ADD COLUMN id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY;
```

Then to insert a row (in xcode 11.4 vapor 4 fluentpostgresql) remove id from your POST request json e.g.:

```
{"section":1,"operator_id":4415 ... etc.}
```

To update an existing row, include the id in the json. The following in routes.swift handles both insert and update:

```
app.post("complaint") { req -> EventLoopFuture<Complaint> in
    let complaint = try req.content.decode(Complaint.self)
    if let id = complaint.id {
        print("60p \(id)") // Optional(6005)
    }
    return complaint.save(on: req.db)
        .map { complaint }
}
```